# How to calculate interval [a,b]

Tags: c++

I am a newbie in C++ in my first little project is making me a headache.

If I understand the pbolem correctly, I need to cout the sum of the interval [a,b] which should mean: 
 17 + 18 + 19 + 20 + 21..... + 52 = ? (correct me if I am wrong!) 
   I tried with while, do-while and they both ended up being an endless loop so now I am trying with for loop which gets me to just increasing the value of a until it reaches 52.

> ```
> #include <iostream>
>
> int main(int argc, char* argv[])
> {
>     const int a = 17;
>     const int b = 52;
>
>     int summe = 0;
>
>   for(summe = a; summe <=b; summe++)
>
>     std::cout << "Summe: " << summe << "\n";
>
>    return 0;
> }
> ```

Comment: You need two variables: one, the iterator variable, to count the number you're adding, and one to contain the sum so far.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your code simply dumps the numbers you are expecting to sum, but you've forgotten to sum up them!

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    const int a = 17;
    const int b = 52;

    int summe, number;

    for(summe = 0, number = a; number <= b; number++)
        summe += number;

    std::cout << "Summe: " << summe << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

or, an easier way: no loops at all!

```
int a = 17;
int b = 52;
int sum = (a + b) * (b - a + 1) / 2.0
```